# CSS :not(:last-child):after selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have a list of elements, which are styled like this:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

li:not(:last-child):after {
    content:' |';
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Outputs `One | Two | Three | Four | Five |` instead of `One | Two | Three | Four | Five`

Anyone know how to CSS select all but the last element?

You can see the definition of the `:not()` selector [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation)

Answer (score 475, accepted):

If it's a problem with the not selector, you can set all of them and override the last one

```
li:after
{
  content: ' |';
}
li:last-child:after
{
  content: '';
}
```

or if you can use before, no need for last-child

```
li+li:before
{
  content: '| ';
}
```

Comment: This is actually the only way to get it to work as far back as IE8 (sorry, no cheetos for IE7 and earlier).  `li:not(:first-child):before` is a little bit too scary for the older versions of Internet Explorer to tackle.

Answer (score 272):

Every things seems correct. You might want to use the following css selector instead of what you used.

```
ul > li:not(:last-child)::after
```

Comment: @ScottBeeson This is the best awnser for modern browser, but accepted answer work with old browsers. (I agree with you, this should be the accepted one)

Answer (score 37):

For me it work fine

```
&:not(:last-child){
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
```

Comment: This answer might relate to SCSS rather than CSS.

Comment: This worked for me with Material-UI as well:

`"&:not(:first-child)": { ... styles }`

Answer (score 26):

Your example as written works perfectly in Chrome 11 for me. Perhaps your browser just doesn't support the `:not()` selector?

You may need to use JavaScript or similar to accomplish this cross-browser. jQuery implements [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) in its selector API.

Comment: I solved this by doing `li:not(:first-child):before` and adding the vertical bar before.  I was working with the stable version of Chrome that doesn't seem to support last-child.  The Canary build does.  Thanks for the answer tho.

Answer (score 23):

An example using CSS

```
  ul li:not(:last-child){
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(153, 151, 151, 0.75);
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

Your sample does not work in IE for me, you have to specify **Doctype header** in your document to render your page in standard way in IE to use the content CSS property:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<html>

<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
</ul>

</html>
```

**Second way is to use CSS 3 selectors**

```
li:not(:last-of-type):after
{
    content:           " |";
}
```

But you still need to specify Doctype

**And third way is to use JQuery with some script like following:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<html>

<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("li:not(:last)").append(" | ");
    });
</script>
```

Advantage of third way is that you dont have to specify doctype and jQuery will take care of compatibility.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> is the new HTML5 standard.

Comment: This is awesome and modern way to deal with this. I was struggling with :last-child, then I found your answer. This one is perfect! :not(:last-of-type):after

Answer (score -1):

Remove the : before last-child and the :after and used

```
 ul li:not(last-child){
 content:' |';
}
```

Hopefully,it should work

Comment: It does not.  You also need a colon in front of last-child.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the : before last-child and the :after and used

```
ul > li:not(:last-child):after {
   border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I checked again, I used this method and there is no problem