# Vertical line between divs

Tags: html, css

I want to add a vertical line between the green blocks in the following image. I am using `:after` to do that. However I do not want to display the line after the last block. Is there any trick to do that?

[image]

**CSS:**

```
.block{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: green;
    float: left;
}

.block:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/rhwb7b2o/

**Note:** The height of the list items varies. HTML markup can be changed if required.

Comment: Here is an answer that will help you:
[stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449872/css-notlast-childafter-selector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to the `li` elements so that each line does not cover the whole `ul`.

Then add `li:last-child .block{position:relative;overflow:hidden;}` to handle the last element.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qj2dbdkz/

Comment: @user1355300: I updated your own JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rhwb7b2o/1/ - To achieve the acquired effect of the ending portion of the line, you could also add a `li:last-child .block:after` with a defined height of 17px;

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:not` selector with the `:last-child` selector. Like this:

```
.block:not(:last-child):after { /* ... */ }
```