# How can I set a CSS Select for all but the last child?

Tags: css

I have this CSS:

```
.btn-group > .btn {
    margin-right: 0; // << I want this for all except last child
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Is there a way that I can make this margin-right work for all .btn except the last child?

Comment: Did you try `.btn-group > .btn:not(:last-child)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS :not(:last-child):after selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449872/css-notlast-childafter-selector)

Comment: An SO search on "not last child css" would have turned up the existing answer easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)  **negation** CSS pseudo-class

```css
.btn-group > .btn:not(:last-of-type) {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <div class="btn">Button</div>
  <div class="btn">Button</div>
  <div class="btn">Button</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, but why don't you show him how to use this idea in the context of the actual situation he presented?

Comment: Very nice. I learned now what last-of-type means. Never heard of that before.

Comment: How is `last-of-type` different and/or better here than `last-child`?

Comment: @torazaburo I am not sure what is full context of question but i guess its something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/27/ also this qualifies as answer for question `How can I set a CSS Select for all but the last child?`

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```css
.btn-group > .btn:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 0; 
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: This will fail to set `position` and `border-radius` on the last child.

Answer (score -1):

use the :not() selector

```
.btn-group > .btn:not(#someid) {
    margin-right: 0;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Then assign `id="someid"` to the innermost child

and create a new CSS

```
.btn#someid {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

for the last child

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `:not(:last-child)`?

Comment: This won't do what he wants, because it will fail to set `position` and `border-radius` on the last child. Also, note that `:not()` is not a selector, it's a **pseudo-class**.