# Select child tags :after element, except last

Tags: css

I've an angular app, where I have custom components (tags) inside `div`:

```
<div class="parent">
    <custom-1></custom-1>
    <custom-2></custom-2>
    <custom-3></custom-3>
    <custom-4></custom-4>
</div>
```

I want to select all child tag's `:after` inside `.parent`, so I can create a separator line between components, except after last one.

Currently I've selected only all:

```
.parent > *:after {
    content: "";
    height: 60%;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 5px;
}
```

It seems, that `*` is ignoring the `:last-of-type`, because if I used it like this: `.parent > *:last-of-type:after`, it doesn't selected anything.

Comment: `.parent > :not(:last-child)::after`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS :not(:last-child):after selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449872/css-notlast-childafter-selector)

Comment: @caramba I've custom tags. That question is bound to list tags.

Comment: @Gabriel in this case it does not matter which kind of tag it is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about your code, but you may not even need the `*` you can combine `:last-child` and `:after` like so

```css
.parent > :after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: orange;
}


.parent > :last-child:after {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

The `*` as you use it would be needed to select all elements inside the `.parent` element. So if your child elements in `.parent` have even more child elements

**[Last of type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)** will not work because `:after` is a pseudo element and `:last-of-type` will check the type of elements (like `div`, `span`, `p`) to select

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the `*` selector. It works now, thank you!

Comment: @Gabriel glad to hear, happy coding!

Comment: I learnt something new too, didn't know about the *. This is awesome!

Comment: @Gabriel this might be what you really want => https://stackoverflow.com/a/17144965/2008111

Answer (score -1):

you can use one common class for your components if it is possible like

```
.parent > :after {
content: "";
display: block;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
margin: 5px;
background-color: orange;
}
<div class="parent">
   <custom-1 class="mychild"></custom-1>
   <custom-2 class="mychild"></custom-2>
   <custom-3 class="mychild"></custom-3>
   <custom-4 class="mychild"></custom-4>
</div>
```